# where can i see Service Cloud Console in my free developer edition?

Tags: service-cloud-console

i updated the user as a Service cloud user in user settings. But, where can i see Service Cloud Console in my free developer edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example application for the service console included in the developer edition, but it isn't enabled for any profiles in my recent dev orgs.

Navigate to Setup -> Create -> Apps and you will see Sample Console in the apps list.

Click the edit link next to this and scroll to the bottom of the page and you will see the profile availability - on mine its empty:

[image]

Check the boxes for the profiles that you want to have access and click the 'Save' button.  The sample console application will then appear in the applications menu at the top right.

You can also create your own custom service console applications if you don't like the sample one - simply select the console radio button after you click the New button.

Comment: Thanks @Bob. I got it, now it is showing in my org. But, one question, Will it contains all the features like 
    Service Cloud Console
    Entitlements
    SLAs
as given in this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8876/what-are-the-differences-regarding-cases-in-sales-and-service-cloud/8883#8883

Comment: Yes - its a tabbed way to access Salesforce records, so all of the functionality that is accessible through the regular UI is also available in the service cloud console. Plus you can open related records in subtabs etc.  Check out the setup guide at: https://na6.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_console_impl_guide.pdf

Comment: Great @Bob. i will take a look on the Salesforce console documentation. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You have an application called "Sample Console". Look for it on applications:

[image]